# Spyder4 is not plotting anything

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

im using spyder for the first time and it's not plotting the simplest code

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,3,2], b=[3,2,1]))
fig = df.plot(title="Pandas Backend Example", template="simple_white",
              labels=dict(index="time", value="money", variable="option"))
fig.update_yaxes(tickprefix="$")
fig.show()
```

i have tried updating everything, im using anaconda if that is anyhelp
there are no errors and it runs. It should be a simple plot

Comment: Does it throwing any warning ?

Comment: no warnings or anythings

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your settings in Spyder IDE >> Tools >> Preferences >> Ipython Console >> Graphics, are similar to the picture below:

[image]

Then you can run in your command line:

**Plots to appear in a separate window**

```
%matplotlib qt
```

**Plots to appear inline**:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

In addition,

You can try also --> Tools >> Preferences >> IPython console >> Graphics >> Backend:Inline, change "Inline" to "Automatic", click "OK", and then reset the kernel.

Hopefully the above will help.

Comment: i tried all of that and nothing works. im using spyder in anaconda if that mattes